# SWT: Can't find source of Widget is disposed Exception

Tags: java, widget, swt, dispose, jface

I'm stucking at a *Widget is disposed* Exception when closing a SWT dialog. I know that this tells me that something tries to call a widget which is alredy disposed, but I can't find out why this happen. Here is some excerpt from my code:

```
final Display display = Display.getCurrent();
final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.RESIZE | SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MIN | SWT.MAX | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
final ConstraintDialog dialog = new ConstraintDialog(shell);
dialog.open();
```

---

```
protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent) {
    final Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    container.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    final Label lblSource = new Label(grpNewConstraint, SWT.NONE);
    lblSource.setFont(JFaceResources.getFontRegistry().getBold(""));
    lblSource.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
    lblSource.setText("Source Feature");
    new Label(grpNewConstraint, SWT.NONE);

    final ListViewer lvConstraints = new ListViewer(grpExistingConstraints, SWT.V_SCROLL);
    lvConstraints.setContentProvider(new ConstraintDialogContentProvider());
    lvConstraints.setLabelProvider(new ConstraintDialogLabelProvider());
    lvConstraints.setInput(this.fm);
    final List listConstraints = lvConstraints.getList();
    final GridData gd_listConstraints = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, true, true, 1, 1);
    gd_listConstraints.heightHint = 120;
    listConstraints.setLayoutData(gd_listConstraints);

    final Button btnAddConstraint = new Button(composite_Buttons, SWT.NONE);
    btnAddConstraint.setToolTipText("Use th form above to add a new Constraint");
    btnAddConstraint.setText("Add Constraint");
    btnAddConstraint.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent event) {
                ..........
                lvConstraints.refresh();
                final Point grpSize = grpExistingConstraints.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT); 
                grpExistingConstraints.setSize(grpSize);
    ....
    });
```

Here is the error stack, which doesn't helped me at all to find the source of the error:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.addFocusListener(Control.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DialogCellEditor$2.widgetSelected(DialogCellEditor.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

If I open and close the widget, no exception appears. But when I open the dialog, do some action (use the button) and close it, the exception is shown

------------ Update -------------------

Due to your comment, I've extended my code snippet:

```
public CellEditor createPropertyEditor(final Composite parent) {
        return new ExtendedDialogCellEditor(parent, getLabelProvider()) {
            @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
            @Override
            protected Object openDialogBox(final Control cellEditorWindow) {
                final Display display = Display.getCurrent();
                final Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.RESIZE | SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MIN | SWT.MAX
                        | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                if (ConstraintPropertyDescriptor.this.object instanceof FeatureModel) {
                    final FeatureModel fm = (FeatureModel) ConstraintPropertyDescriptor.this.object;
                    final ConstraintDialog dialog = new ConstraintDialog(fm, shell);
                    dialog.open();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Error is in `DialogCellEditor` - do you have something using that?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've made an update of my code snippet. Maybe there is the error?

Comment: Creating a `Shell` like that is not usual, you should be using `cellEditorWindow.getShell()` as the parent shell of your `ConstraintDialog`.

Comment: Ok, I changes this, but it's still the same exception. The line in at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DialogCellEditor$2.widgetSelected(DialogCellEditor.java:247) tells me: "// Re-add the listener once the dialog closes
button.addFocusListener(getButtonFocusListener());

Comment: What is `ExtendedDialogCellEditor`?

Comment: org.eclipse.emf.common.ui.celleditor.ExtendedDialogCellEditor.ExtendedDialogCellEditor -> This uses a label provider to display a dialog cell editor.....Maybe I'm not allowed to return null here